# How is $\pi$ defined? How does one calculate the value of $\pi$ to a given precision?

Tags: geometry

How is $\pi$ defined? How does one calculate the value of $\pi$ to a given precision?

Comment: This question is too vague. A complete answer (especially to the first part) would be too long for this site. I would suggest doing some of your own research first then posting to clarify any doubts you may have. Even Wikipedia would do the trick. For now, I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Definition

Comment: "Too broad" is actually a better reason to close, but I didn't spot it when I cast my vote.

Comment: This is a very nice book. Some parts you can read online [Pi - Unleashed, by Jörg Arndt, Christoph Haenel](https://books.google.at/books?id=QwwcmweJCDQC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Deepak Rather than finding excuses for closing questions, wouldn't it be great to actually give some context to the OP on the different posible definitions of $\pi$?

Comment: It can be calculated in [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) ways.

Comment: @David Your use of "excuses" seems to imply that you think that I'm trying to get this closed for inappropriate, petty or selfish reasons. I assure you this is not the case. I'm voting to close because this is a poor question. A question can be poor for many reasons, and one of those is that it's asking for too broad an answer to be suitable for the context in which it's asked. A poor question is unlikely to have good answers, and, as a matter of fact, I think your own answer is poor as it's inadequate to the task. I haven't downvoted it (at present), I'm just giving you my honest opinion.

Comment: @Deepak I cannot think about a less broad, more specific question than asking for a definition (and, indeed, a very important definition in Mathematics!) Please explain why my answer is poor

Comment: @David As you yourself mentioned, there are multiple ways to define $\pi$ (I wouldn't call it "multiple ways to reach the *same* definition"). The question asked for how $\pi$ is defined. There are too many definitions, from disparate disciplines, to give a reasonably comprehensive answer. You can define $\pi$ geometrically, trigonometrically, via calculus and even with probability theory. In each of those I mentioned, there are numerous definitions. Your answer is poor (in my opinion) because it only gives one definition and doesn't even link to a resource with the "multiple ways" mentioned.

Comment: @David In any case, the answer is (rightfully, in my view) closed now, and I think you should drop this. At any rate, I will not be responding any more as I consider the matter closed.

Comment: A frequent definition of $\pi$ is "the smallest positive root of $\sin x$". The sine function can be defined from its Taylor development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to reach the same definition of $\pi$, the most natural (or at least, the original) probably being:

Let $C$ be the circumference of a circle of diameter $1$. Then the arc length of a full turn around $C$ is $\pi$

You can get arbitrarely accurate representations of $\pi$ by taking enough terms of a sequence that converges to $\pi$. A very famous one (although not the most efficient one) is the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Now, you can get as close as $\pi$ as you want by computing $\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + ... + \frac{1}{K^2}$ for a big enough $K$

Comment: It should be "Let $C$ be the circumference of **a circle** of diameter $1$".

Comment: @md2perpe English is weird

Comment: Yes, but the word *circumference* does not imply the figure being a circle.

Comment: @md2perpe True.. But weird since in Spanish (and as far as I am aware, all "decent" languages), a circumference is a curve that encloses a circle. Even in English, I wouldn't call "circumference" to the curve around an ellipse, but well... No problem

Comment: Also in my mother tongue, Swedish, many people would assume that *diameter*, and probably also *circumference*, implies a circle. This is a site about mathematics however. In mathematics "circumference" normally means the length of the boundary of a region, which doesn't even have to be convex.

Comment: As a native speaker of English I tend to disagree. To me "perimeter" better fits that definition, and "circumference" does indeed connote a circle.

Comment: The Basel formula indeed leads to the value of $\pi$, but converges too slowly for practical use. The Machin formula is preferable (and there are many much better ones).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure! As already explained, the point of my answer was just to provide an example, not necessarely the most efficient one. Anyway, it all depends on what you want to achieve. If you only need something like 6 digits, I don't think the extra $10^{-7}$ seconds it will take to your program to calculate ithem will make any difference